# TypeError: on_quit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having this problem while trying to multithread with tkinter's mainloop. Everything works if I don't try to multithread, but if I do it gives me an error.

I'm implementing this class to get and set characters coordinates in a certain game and this part works, however the application won't let me quit. I tried setting self.root.protocol's second parameter as self.on_quit() and self.on_quit(self), but it just instantly executes it.

```py
class PositionGUI:

    EXIT_FLAG = False

    def __init__(self, process: DSProcess):

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_quit)
        ...
        Thread(target=self.update, args=(self, process)).start()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update(self, process: DSProcess):
        while not self.EXIT_FLAG:
            ...

    def on_quit(self):
        self.EXIT_FLAG = True
        self.root.destroy()


class DarkShell(DSProcess):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DarkShell, self).__init__()
        ...
        Thread(target=PositionGUI.__init__, args=(PositionGUI, self)).start()
```

On-quit method is supposed to set a flag for the update function to finish and close this part of the application, but instead it gives me this error:
"TypeError: on_quit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Comment: There are no paranthesis, with them it throws the error right away.

Comment: I see a few things I would not do with this class. I wonder if your `while` loop is going to cause problems. Please provide a testable example. The code you have provided cannot be tested.

Comment: The 1st major problem I see is that you are placing tkinter into a 2nd thread and tkinter needs to be in the main thread for everything to work properly.

Comment: `self.update` is a bound method; it does not need `self` as an additional argument in order to create the thread.

Answer (score 1):

1. Tkinter needs to be in the main thread if you even really need threading (often you don't there are workarounds for most issue)
2. Your `EXIT_FLAG = False`is not defined as a class attribute so a call to `self.EXIT_FLAG` will not work.
3. Instead of doing `from tkinter import *` use `import tkinter as tk` this will prevent any overlapping imports from causing errors.

So without something I can actually test I can only guess at your real problem but take this example and let me know if it helps.

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread


class PositionGUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, process: DSProcess):
        super().__init__()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_quit)
        self.EXIT_FLAG = False
        ...
        Thread(target=self.update, args=(self, process)).start()
        self.mainloop()

    def update(self, process: DSProcess):
        while not self.EXIT_FLAG:
            pass

    def on_quit(self):
        self.EXIT_FLAG = True # note that this line does nothing useful 
        self.root.destroy()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It certainly helps to know that I should define the flag as a class variable.

Comment: I tried solving this by defining root and protocol inside the second class and giving the root to the init as a parameter, but then it started giving me Runtime errors, so I gues here's where multithreading problem arises.

Comment: @Nahnahchi again you do not want to define root inside the class. Instead make the class inherit from Tk() so the class itself it the root. Then you can pass `self` to anything that needs root. That said you need to build this with Tkinter being the main thread. What you are doing now is running tkinter in the 2nd thread not the main thread.